# Calling web API from MVC Controller to build and pass model to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to grasp many concepts that are new to me and I need some clarifications on the best way to create and pass my strongly typed model from my MVC Controller to its Razor view using a Web API.

As seen in many examples, you usually create your model from some repository and then pass it to the view (strongly typed or not) and then use the Razor syntax which gives you access to your model to build the html not necessarily having to use JavaScript.

Where things get complicated for me is when I want to make use of the Web API to create the model I want to use just like I would use it as I describe in the previous paragraph.

Should I call the new HTTPClient to call the Web API service from within my controller?
Will I need to deserialize and format the response? etc...

I always see calls and manipulations from scripts within the view...

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your setup. Are you using `ApiController`s to return data to a view, or are you calling another WebAPI controller from inside a standard MVC controller?

Comment: Hi James, I am calling a WebAPI Controller from inside a standard MVC controller.  For now, since I am kind of practicing, it could be an apicontroller from the same MVC app but I will eventually have to build standalone WebAPI services which I will call from other apps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your WebAPI is a separate endpoint i.e. not part of your existing site, then yes you will have to send a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) from inside your controller and then serialize the data from the response and pass that into your view.

Alternatively you could call the API directly from inside your view via AJAX, however, I am not sure if you need your controller to do something with the data before it comes down to the view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer James.  Is it right to say that there is no need for apicontrollers IF the only consumer is my MVC app?

Comment: The way to look at it is - ApiControllers return *data* e.g. XML/Json for comsumption by a client, standard MVC controllers return *views* to be served to the browser. Standard controllers can also return data but for the purpose of this think of them as being *view* controllers. So taking everything into consideration, ask yourself what type of controller you need...